# A little CSS trickery with border-image gradients is needed

Tags: css, border, linear-gradients, gradient

I'm really hoping someone can help with this. I have a ul li unordered list thing going on, with the following css being applied:

```
ul li {
  float: left;
  /* border-right: 2px solid white; */
  border-width: 0px;
  border-right-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))) 1 100%;
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
  -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
  -o-border-image: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
}

ul li:last-child {
  border: 0;
}
```

I've so far managed to achieve the following effect for my nav bar blocks:

[image]

*HOWEVER (!!), this was the desired result:

[image]

I know it seems strange to have these sorts of borders - but it gives me the desired thickness, and the client wants some funky hover effects. Hopefully someone can help...

All I need to understand is how to bring the transparent top and bottom sections in...

Comment: paste html as well to make things easy for others.

Comment: @shahid I can't really because I'm using Vue.js bindings - li is from for loop.

Comment: provide the full code HTML/CSS (show source in your browser and you will get the structure) that shows your issue. Hint: You can fake a brder via bg gradient and resize them via background-size . here two old demos of mine to show the idea https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bBGBwb & https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/IGliC and a third one https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pKwby ... very basic your imagination will do the design

Comment: Well then try Css Pseudo after and before for your borders and keep border opacity.